# How can I fix ceph commands hanging after a reboot?

Tags: ceph

I'm pretty new to Ceph, so I've included all my steps I used to set up my cluster since I'm not sure what is or is not useful information to fix my problem.

I have 4 CentOS 8 VMs in VirtualBox set up to teach myself how to bring up Ceph. 1 is a client and 3 are Ceph monitors. Each ceph node has 6 8Gb drives. Once I learned how the networking worked, it was pretty easy.

I set each VM to have a NAT (for downloading packages) and an internal network that I called "ceph-public". This network would be accessed by each VM on the 10.19.10.0/24 subnet. I then copied the ssh keys from each VM to every other VM.

I followed [this documentation](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephadm/install/#bootstrap-a-new-cluster) to install cephadm, bootstrap my first monitor, [and added the other two nodes as hosts](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephadm/host-management/#cephadm-adding-hosts). Then I added all available devices as OSDs, [created my pools](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/rados/operations/pools/), then [created my images](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/rbd/rados-rbd-cmds/), then copied my /etc/ceph folder from the bootstrapped node to my client node. On the client, I ran `rbd map mypool/myimage` to mount the image as a block device, then used mkfs to create a filesystem on it, and I was able to write data and see the IO from the bootstrapped node. All was well.

Then, as a test, I shutdown and restarted the bootstrapped node. When it came back up, I ran `ceph status` but it just hung with no output. Every single ceph and rbd command now hangs and I have no idea how to recover or properly reset or fix my cluster.

Has anyone ever had the `ceph` command hang on their cluster, and what did you do to solve it?

Comment: I assume that your ceph.conf file still only has the one MON node as "mon host". Add all your MONs to that line. But it also sounds like the MON container on the bootstrap host doesn't start for some reason. If the other two containers are running, at least ceph commands should work if you add all MONs. If that works you need to fix failing container starts.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share a similar experience. I also tried some time ago to perform some tests on Ceph (mimic i think) an my VMs on my VirtualBox acted very strange, nothing comparing with actual bare metal servers so please bare this in mind... the tests are not quite relevant.

As regarding your problem, try to see the following:

- have at least 3 monitors (or an even number). It's possible that hang is because of monitor election.
- make sure the networking part is OK (separated VLANs for ceph servers and clients)
- DNS is resolving OK. (you have added the servername in hosts)

...just my 2 cents...